# Entries from the database whose id correspond to the array

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I use mysql database

I have the array `$arr = [61, 14, 197, 101, 229, 240, 144, 239, 75];`

And query `$query = "Select * From cases where cases.id IN ($arr)";`

I get the list, in which the first entry - 14 (the smallest id)

But I need ordnung correspondign the sequence in $arr (first 61)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 1):

Any database system tends to have some type of functionality for ordering some particular column based on some comma separated list of values.

If you are using MySQL for example this can be achieved by adding this

`ORDER BY FIELD(cases.id, $arr)`

Example

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID in (4,2,3)
ORDER BY FIELD(CustomerID,4,2,3);
```